# Ruby sort_by confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I'm trying to sort by an aspect of my object (score). This is what I have so far, but I get error messages such as "undefined method score".

```
class object
    def initialize(likes, comments, score)
        @no_of_likes=likes
        @no_of_comments=comments
        @score =score
    def calculateScore
        #Assigns a score to each element of the array, based off of            algorithm
        @score = (@no_of_likes + @no_of_comments)
    end
def sortByScore()

    arr = [o1 =Object.new(40, 35, 0), o2 =Object.new(100, 2, 0), o3 = Object.new(1, 150, 0)]

    for obj in arr
        obj.calculateScore
    end
    #sorts by score
    arr = ar.sort_by &:score
    puts arr.inspect
end
```

Comment: You have a `@score` instance variable but no `score` method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". If your code was correctly indented it'd help you figure out problems. Your code won't be accepted by Ruby because it's missing multiple `end` statements. Also, it's a really bad idea to call a class `object`. First, classes should be CamelCase, so it'd be `Object`, but there's already an [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html) class and overwriting it is a really bad idea.

Comment: You really need to clear up this code, this isn't valid Ruby. Additionally convention holds that methods have names like `sort_by_score` and empty arguments are omitted, that is `()` is almost never specified. Assigning unused variables inside an array is also equally bewildering and messy. On top of all this, don't call your class `object`, as `Object` is the basis of all Ruby objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I renamed your class to Obj, object is not a good name. Obj isn't good either. Try to name the class something that describes what you are up to(how about Scorekeeper?).

```
class Obj
  attr_reader :score

  def initialize(likes, comments, score)
    @no_of_likes = likes
    @no_of_comments = comments
    @score = score
  end

  # Assigns a score to each element of the array, based off of algorithm
  def calculateScore
    @score = (@no_of_likes + @no_of_comments)
  end
end
```

Notice the added line:

```
  attr_reader :score
```

That is equivalent to:

```
  def score
    @score
  end
```

which is your missing/undefined method:

```
arr = [Obj.new(40, 35, 0), Obj.new(1, 150, 0), Obj.new(100, 2, 0)]
arr.map(&:score)
 => [0, 0, 0]

arr.each { |obj| obj.calculateScore }
arr.map(&:score)
 => [75, 151, 102] 

arr = arr.sort_by(&:score)
arr.map(&:score)
 => [75, 102, 151]
```

Comment: I come from the world of Java/Python, would you say that the line

 " attr_reader :score "

is kind of like a "getter" method for the score value?

Comment: @DannyTobackdtdirt - Yes. Also attr_writer(setter) and attr_accessor(getter/setter).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of these objects,

```
@collection.sort_by{|object| object.score}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
R = Struct.new(:confusion)

Ruby = Array.new(9){R.new(rand)}
sorted = Ruby.sort_by(&:confusion)
```